# styled scroll in bootstrap dropdown menu not work

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I use dropdown in bootstrap and content is tall, so I need scrooll-y
but I don't want use browser default scroll bar and I use → [this script](http://www.queness.com/post/11809/transform-jscrollpane-into-mac-osx-lion-scroll-bar)
this script work well, but when use this script with bootstrap dropdown it does not work

This code for my bootstrap dropdown menu:

```
<button class="notify-bell dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></button>
<div class="dropdown-menu notify_container" id="notify_container" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
<h1>...</h1>
<h2>...</h2>
<div class="action">
    <img class="img-circle-notify" src="images/circle-avatar.png" alt="" title="">
    <span class="user-message-row">....</span>
    <span class="descript-notify">....</span>
    <div class="notify-link">
    <a class="" href="#">.....</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this code for initialize script:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
    var bars = '.jspHorizontalBar, .jspVerticalBar';
    $('.dropdown-menu .notify_container').bind('jsp-initialised', function (event, isScrollable) {

        //hide the scroll bar on first load
        $(this).find(bars).hide();

    }).jScrollPane().hover(

        //hide show scrollbar
        function () {
            $(this).find(bars).stop().fadeTo('fast', 0.9);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find(bars).stop().fadeTo('fast', 0);
        }
    );   
     console.log($('#notify_container'));              
});
</script>
```

you can also see this code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dbneke8b/

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle pls ? I will be more clear.

Comment: What exactly not working?

Comment: this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dbneke8b/

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the following script you are using, even in the fiddle you created in question

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

> $(...).bind(...).jScrollPane is not a function

And in CSS `margin-top: -600px;` may be it's typo or your design requirement

```
.notify_container{
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
    margin: 0 auto; 
    margin-top: -600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is working example

CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.queness.com/resources/html/osx-lion-scrollbar/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css">
```

JS

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.queness.com/resources/html/osx-lion-scrollbar/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.queness.com/resources/html/osx-lion-scrollbar/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

Additional CSS

```
<style>
.notify_container{
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
    margin: 0 auto; 
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.notify_container h1{
    font-family: IRANSans-web;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.notify_container h2{
    font-family: IRANSans-web;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 8px !important;
    color: #757575;

}
.notify_container .action{
    width: 290px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(17, 16, 13, 0.33);
}
</style>
```

Script

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var bars = '.jspHorizontalBar, .jspVerticalBar';
    $('.dropdown-menu .notify_container').bind('jsp-initialised', function (event, isScrollable) {

        //hide the scroll bar on first load
        $(this).find(bars).hide();

    }).jScrollPane().hover(

        //hide show scrollbar
        function () {
            $(this).find(bars).stop().fadeTo('fast', 0.9);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find(bars).stop().fadeTo('fast', 0);
        }
    );   
     console.log($('#notify_container'));              
});
</script>
```

[Working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4unysmd0/1/)